# Enabling OpenSSL on EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, openssl

I am currently trying to install openssl on my ec2 server so that I can get rid of this particular error:

```
 stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:func(148):reason(1040)
```

After doing some research I found out that I would need to enable something in my php.ini file, however, I cannot enable anything that relates to OpenSSL where I would need to make an adjustment like so:

from `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Thats when I realised that I need to install an extension for my php.ini file to have that extension for me to enable it, however I do not know how to install OpenSSL on my ec2 instance server. Can someone offer me any guidance?

Comment: Which OS are you using? If it's linux i guess you can simply ssh on it and make a "sudo apt-get install openssl" or the equivalente for your distro

Comment: Hi @FabioCosta thank you for taking your time to look at this. I am using amazon's `Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2` instance. Is there a way for me to confirm this?

Comment: It seems that the AMI is red hat based. it uses rpm or yum. But before trying to install openssl Try checking if it is installed. And the code you showed would work on a windows machine try adding "extension=openssl.so" instead and see if this solves it

Comment: @FabioCosta Hi, what you said just now sort of flies right over my head. This is what I know so far, I am able to ssh into my instance through my terminal app on my macbook and am greeted by my server's welcome message. Is that where you want me to try your command, on the welcome page?

Comment: @FabioCosta I thought I'd just check whether the `apt-get` command would be recognisable, but its not. The response returned is `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: Ok I just realised on google search that the amazon equivalent is `yum`, which I believe you mentioned already. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Before trying a command see if you can edit your php.ini.Try searching it if you can't find it.Type "find / -name " php.ini" -type f "edit it and add the "extension=openssl.so", restart your server and see if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46965/discussion-between-fabiocosta-and-pavan)

Comment: Then just do:  yum install php-openssl

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would use `yum install openssl` on your server.

Try `yum search opennsll` if you dont see it

They have instructions here for install openssl another way:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html

Comment: I guess openssl is probably already installed, so just trying to change the php.ini and restarting apache could do the trick

Comment: Then just do:  yum install php-openssl

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with:

```
 yum install php-openssl
```

If you need to install the apache module also and if the command above didnt's intalled it do:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

Then check if php.ini has the extension avaible , if you don't know which php.ini you are using you can put the following on a php file:

```
 echo php_ini_loaded_file();
```

Since you are using linux find the line bellow on the file, if it's not there add it to the end:

```
extension=openssl.so
```

After that restart the apache server with

```
 service httpd restart
```

You should have ssl installed and can check it with the following on a php file:

```
phpinfo();
```