# Which method to choose when developing a simple iOS Chat Application

Tags: php, ios, chat

I have to develop a simple chat application for iOS devices.
I tried to do this with this:

When I run my application I call this method:

```
-(void) NewChatMessages{

// Create the asynchronous request.
NSString *chatURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.example.com/chat.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:chatURL] 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
timeoutInterval:10.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------234213413243214124321456566";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myTel\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myTel] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

// Create url connection and fire request
chatConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

This request, calls a php script that checks if there are new messages for me or not:

```
$myTel = $_POST['myTel'];

$exist=mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE tel = '$myTel'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($esiste);
if($num_rows > 0){

    //there is a new chat message for me! (maybe it's not only one)
    echo "1";
}
else{

    //there aren't new chat messages for me
    echo "0";
}
```

When I receive the response (using URLRequest delegate), if I received 1, I download new messages, else nothing.
Then I call this method again (every time I receive a response) to create a new URL connection and check if there are new chat messages for me.
This solution works fine, but my question is, is this the right method to develop a chat application?
Isn't this method too recursively and isn't there an excessive memory and data usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal way for your app to be notified of message would be for your server to send push notifications to your app when a user has a new message. This keeps your app from constantly hitting the server just to *check* if something is there. If this is out of your php or iOS skill set I would recommend [Parse](https://www.parse.com). It's hard to sum them up but it's a very powerful platform and they have a [tutorial that demonstrating](https://www.parse.com/tutorials) exactly how to do what your asking.

Comment: What if you want to use you own server to send out the push notifications? Im getting this error atm, please have a look at my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754008/enabling-openssl-on-ec2-instance-free-tier-without-restarting-server

Comment: I'm not strong with PHP so I can't help you there. My answer was addressing your original question only.

Comment: 'your question'? lol Wrong user mate, I am not the OP. Alright, no problem, thanks; I thought you may have had an answer to a question I posted months ago on SO.

Comment: @Pavan my apologizes :-P I wish I could help you out, I know enough PHP to identify PHP code. Beyond that I'm useless.

Comment: Ok, i didn't use parse but i have understood how push notifications works. I have some problems to server side (php), but this was the solution i needed, so my application don't have to constantly contact the server. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try socket programming, instead of API based chat application.
Try using this tutorial. [Networking Tutorial for iOS: How To Create A Socket Based iPhone App and Server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

Although this tutorial is based on Python as server side script, but this is just for an idea, you can easily work on PHP as well.